# Convert flat tree array into MYSQL where clause, with siblings respresenting OR and descendents representing AND

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, algorithm

I have a flat array containing tree data. The tree can be of any length and be as deep as the user requires. Each node has the following data:

```
id: 1,
parent: 0,

id: 2,
parent: 1,
equation: 'user.id = 1'

id: 3,
parent: 2,
equation: 'user.id <> 2'        

id: 4,
parent: 1,
equation: 'user.id = 4'
```

What I'd need to design is an algorithm to turn this array into a string containing a mysql clause resembling:

```
WHERE ( user.id = 1 AND user.id <> 2 ) OR user.id = 4
```

Again I can't restrict how complex the logic in this query might become, I simply need to allow for any possibility, so I'll need to probably convert the data to an associative array and work through it recursively.

Each portion of the query is generated by an interface where users can create segmentation rules for users in their database. So they might want to select users whose:

```
WHERE user.id = 3 AND user.id != 4 AND user.date_of_birth < 1234567 AND user.date_of_birth > 7654321 AND user.last_purchased_date > 1234567;
```

Which I need to generate using this data source:

```
id: 1,
parent: 0,

id: 2,
parent: 1,
equation: 'user.id = 3'

id: 3,
parent: 2,
equation: 'user.id != 4'        

id: 4,
parent: 3,
equation: 'user.date_of_birth < 1234567'

id: 5,
parent: 4,
equation: 'user.date_of_birth > 7654321'

id: 5,
parent: 5,
equation: 'user.last_purchase_date > 1234567'
```

You can see from the data source, a child element represents AND (descendent nodes add AND clauses) and a sibling element represents an OR.
ie they have the same parent:

```
id: 1,
parent: 0,

id: 2,
parent: 1,
equation: 'users.id = 3'

id: 3,
parent: 1,
equation: 'users.id = 4'
```

This would result in an OR statement

```
WHERE user.id = 3 OR user.id = 4
```

The tree/data source can have any number of nodes, containing any number of equations and I need to build a query string using this data structure to represent AND/OR compounds.

I'm a bit lost as to where to begin with the algorithm.

Comment: When you say as deep as the user requires. What does depth look like here? You're example array only demonstrates one dimension. Overall, just supply as much information as you can; more details. You could imagine it's tough to completely understand what you need.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I've added more detail, hopefully enough to give you a better idea of what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this function will build an array with all the clause elements in the correct place, I simply need to implode the array. Could also be done with a concatenated string.

```
function where_builder( $elements = array(), &$clause = array(), $index = 0)
{
    //
    $element_children = $this->return_array_where( $elements, 'parent', $elements[$index]['id'] );

    //
    $x=0;
    foreach( $element_children as $key => $value ) 
    {
        if( $x > 0 )
            array_push( $clause, ' OR ' );

        if( count( $element_children ) > 1  )
            array_push( $clause, ' ( ' );

        //
        $element_grandchildren = $this->return_array_where( $elements, 'parent', $value['id'] );

        //  
        array_push( $clause, $value['equation'] );
        //
        if( count( $element_grandchildren ) > 0 )
        {   
            array_push( $clause, ' AND ' );

            $pointer = $this->get_first_key_where( $elements, 'id', $value['id'] );

            $this->where_builder( $elements, $clause, $pointer );
        }

        if( count( $element_children ) > 1 )
            array_push( $clause, ' ) ' );

        $x++;
    }
    return $clause;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was fun to do this!

```
$test=[ ['id'=> 1,'parent'=> 0],
        ['id'=> 2, 'parent'=> 1, 'equation'=> 'users.id = 1'],
        ['id'=> 3, 'parent'=> 2, 'equation'=> 'users.id <> 2'],        
        ['id'=> 4, 'parent'=> 1, 'equation'=> 'users.id = 4']
        ];
$in_where=[];       

echo  whereFromArray($test,$in_where);

function whereFromArray($array=[],&$in_where)
{
    $return='';

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        $result=search($array, 'parent', $value['id']);

        if (count($result)) {//has children

            $return.= 'OR ('. str_replace('OR ', 'AND ', whereFromArray($result,$in_where)) .') ';

        }elseif(!in_array($value['id'], $in_where)){

            $return.= 'OR '.$value['equation'].' ';
            $in_where[]=$value['id'];
        }
    }

    return ltrim(ltrim($return,'AND '),'OR ');

}

function search($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array)) {


        foreach ($array as $subarray) {

            if (isset($subarray[$key]) && $subarray[$key] === $value) {

                $results[] = $subarray;

            }

        }

    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems to make every compound an OR, rather than AND/OR depending on it's relationship to the surrounding equations. I've added more detail above which might make the problem more clear.

Comment: mmm your need just to make some modification to do that with my answer

Comment: Yes, you definitely set me in the right direction. I can build on this. Thank you.